# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that contains a dynamic query. My reason for using a dynamic query is that I need to pass between 0 and 3 parameters to the same query.

Right now, when I run the procedure, I get the following error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.*

Where is my error?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [harris].[ebill](@cycle_ char(15),@route_ char(15),@account_ char(64))
As
SET NOCOUNT on
Begin
--variable declarations
declare @SQLQuery NVarchar(4000)

declare @errcount int
declare @count_2 int
declare @jour_no int
declare @cnt int
declare @loop_counter int
declare @loop_count int
declare @trans_date_count int
declare @batch_number_count int

declare @account_no char (10)
declare @occupant_code char(2)
declare @name char(30)
declare @email_address char(70)
declare @serv_street_no char(5)
declare @serv_street_mod char(3)
declare @serv_street char(20)
declare @batchnumber char(10)

declare @net numeric(18,2)
declare @owing numeric(18,2)

declare @trans_date datetime
declare @ebill_date_sent datetime
declare @duedate datetime
declare @billdate datetime

--cursors being used for recordsets 
declare @ebill_list_cur CURSOR
declare @trans_date_cur CURSOR
declare @rs_cur CURSOR

--temp table to store recordset being returned
create table #ebill_list
(
   account_no char(10), 
   occupant_code char(2), 
   name char(30), 
   email_address char(70),
   serv_street_no char(5), 
   serv_street_mod char(3), 
   serv_street char(20), 
   net numeric(18,2), 
   owing numeric(18,2), 
   duedate datetime, 
   billdate datetime
)

create table #ebill_templist
(
   account_no char(10), 
   occupant_code char(2), 
   name char(30), 
   email_address char(70),
   serv_street_no char(5), 
   serv_street_mod char(3), 
   serv_street char(20)
)


-- Create cursor of ebill customers  

Set @SQLQuery = 'select account_no, occupant_code, [name], email_address, serv_street_no, serv_street_mod, serv_street '
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'from pu_account, wbaccesm '
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'where pu_account.debtor_no = wbaccesm.debtor_no '
Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'and wbaccesm.email_notice in (''B'',''Y'')' 

if @cycle_ <> ''
  begin
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' and pu_account.cycle_ in ('
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + @cycle_ +')'
  end

if @route_ <> ''
  begin
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' and pu_account.route_ in ('
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + @route_ +')'
  end

if @account_ <> ''
  begin
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' and pu_account.account_no in ('
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + @account_ +')'
  end

SET @SQLQuery = 'SELECT account_no, occupant_code, [name], email_address, serv_street_no, serv_street_mod, serv_street INTO #ebill_templist FROM (' + @SQLQuery + ')'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery

set @errcount = 0
set @ebill_list_cur = cursor fast_forward
    for
       select account_no, occupant_code, name, email_address, serv_street_no, serv_street_mod, serv_street from #ebill_templist
    open @ebill_list_cur
    fetch next from @ebill_list_cur
        into @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street

-- Loop through the cursor to see who gets ebill

while @@fetch_status=0
begin


    --Check to see if the account is active
    set @cnt = (select count(*) 
    from pu_account_pay
    where account_no=@account_no
    and occupant_code=@occupant_code
    and end_date is null)

    --if account active proceed
    if @cnt>0 
    begin
        --gets a count of records in the pu_balance_host table for the account
        set @trans_date_count=(select count(*)
            from pu_balance_hist
            where account_no =@account_no
            and occupant_code =@occupant_code
            and trans_date in(select max(last_bill_date) 
                from pu_account_pay
                where account_no =@account_no
                and occupant_code =@occupant_code))

        --if more then 0 then proceed
        if @trans_date_count>0
        begin
            --cursor for transaction date
            set @trans_date_cur = cursor fast_forward

            for select trans_date, jour_no
                from pu_balance_hist
                where account_no =@account_no
                and occupant_code =@occupant_code
                and jour_code='BJ'
                and trans_date in(select max(last_bill_date) 
                    from pu_account_pay
                    where account_no =@account_no
                    and occupant_code =@occupant_code)
            open @trans_date_cur

            fetch next from @trans_date_cur into @trans_date, @jour_no

            begin
                    --get batch number count in pujhhdrh table
                    set @batch_number_count=(select count(*) from pujhhdrh
                        where journalnumber = @jour_no
                    and batchtype = 'BJ')

                    -- if count of batch number is greater then 0 proceed
                    if @batch_number_count>0 
                    begin
                        --get batch number
                        set @batchnumber=(select batchnumber
                        from pujhhdrh
                        where journalnumber = @jour_no
                    and batchtype = 'BJ')

                        set @count_2=(select count(*)
                            from pu_ebill_sent
                            where account_no = @account_no
                            and occupant_code = @occupant_code)

                    --get date from pu_ebill_sent
                    if @count_2 > 0
                    begin
                        set @ebill_date_sent=(select max(ebilldate_sent) 
                        from pu_ebill_sent
                        where account_no = @account_no
                        and occupant_code = @occupant_code)

                    end
                    --if no date then set it to last billing date less 1 day
                    else
                    begin
                        set @ebill_date_sent=@trans_date-1
                    end 

                    --if transdate is greater then last ebill date and last trans date is less then todays then send ebill
                    if @trans_date > @ebill_date_sent
                    begin
                        set @rs_cur = cursor fast_forward
                        for select sum(net) net, sum(owing) owing, max(duedate) duedate, max(billdate) billdate
                        from pujhaccd
                            where batchnumber = @batchnumber
                            and account_no = @account_no
                            and occupant_code = @occupant_code
                            and (billtype > 0 and billtype != 3)
                        open @rs_cur
                        fetch next from @rs_cur into @net, @owing, @duedate, @billdate
                        insert into #ebill_list values(
                        @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street,@net, @owing, @duedate, @billdate)

                            fetch next from @ebill_list_cur
                                into @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                        fetch next from @ebill_list_cur
                                into @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street
                        end     
                end

                --if count of batch number is 0 then proceed to the next record in the original cursor
                else
                begin
                    fetch next from @ebill_list_cur
                        into @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street
                    end

            end
        end

        --If no records in pu_balance_his then go to the next record
        else
        begin
            fetch next from @ebill_list_cur
                into @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street
            end


    end 
    -- if not active then go to next record in the cursor
    else
    begin
        fetch next from @ebill_list_cur
                into @account_no,@occupant_code,@name,@email_address,@serv_street_no,@serv_street_mod, @serv_street
        end
    --end for the while loop
    end

set @loop_count=(select count(*) from #ebill_list)
set @loop_counter=0
while @loop_counter<=@loop_count
begin
    select * from #ebill_list
    return
    set @loop_counter=@loop_counter+1
end


close @rs_cur
deallocate @rs_cur

close @trans_date_cur               
deallocate @trans_date_cur

close @ebill_list_cur
deallocate @ebill_list_cur
end
```

Comment: 3 cursors? For real? You really need to learn about set based operations. Cursors are the performance killer.

Comment: Put `print @SQLQuerty` before any place you do `execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery`. Include the output of that, if any.

Comment: holy cursor-dynamic sql mashup, batman!

Comment: We can't know where is your error if we don't know what sql query you are constructing. Do what Laurence said and then you will realize the problem

Comment: let me clarify --- do you get the error when you execute the procedure itself, or when you try to *create* the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be in your dynamic SQL.  To debug that, the best thing is to out it using PRINT (or look in the profiler) - I suspect you have issues in the parameters which are passed and concatenated as naked strings.

You can probably completely avoid dynamic SQL by using table-valued parameters which can be joined and used in queries just like regular tables.  Since you are using dynamic SQL because you need to check list membership only (as opposed to dynamically choosing conditionals or something else), I would strongly recommend doing that instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx

Comment: @dcoughler, I will add that the specific error that you're receiving is a syntax error and it's nature is such that it's probably with the syntax of the dynamic SQL that you're generating. Follow the advice to print the statement (and maybe even `select len(@SQLQuery)`) to see what's going on. Check for rogue `'`s as well as any reserved words that are not being used for their intended purposes.